# Change the font type of a template

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

In this [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), I want to change the font type to be the default latex font type. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: (I have to after 3 votes)**
Such problems are easy solved by a search inside the text of the appropriate files. Appropriate file for the font, is always the main file but this doesn't means that can not be done in the cls file.(It is not recommended though).

The specific search will probably result font sizes etc and also the problem is that the change can be done without the word font inside the command (like below) but we then hope that the template maintainer or creator commented the inclusion of the package that changes the font.

In some cases, it we can find font changes that using the command `\sfdefault`
and it is a step before go to the last chance that follows.

If we are not lucky and the command that changes the font is not commented or a usual command like the above `sfdefault`, we have to search all the preamble (including the files that are been include) for packages that may change the font.

**For more about packages and commands that can change the font see tha answer of @cfr here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411081/120578**

In XeLaTeX the usual commands can be found with search for `\selectfont`, or "fontfamily" or `\setsansfont`, `\setmainfont` and generally (in the most of the cases) search just for "font"

**Old Answer with 3! votes not really deserved :P**

Comment out line 44 of the file main.tex:

```
%\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
```

Output (in order to not be marked my answer for close):

[image]